# why my query does not read cache when component mounted and every time component load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, react-query

for first time component that has query inside it when mounted , a loading show in the page and when data received data showed . so cache time of data is 5 minutes . I go to another route and very quickly come back to my original route . I expect that data quickly show to users and there is not any loading on page . but in real , my query does not read data from cache and reload again . Login route when mounted fetch data from server first time , then I go to home route and quickly come back to login route but it instead of reading data from cache ,reload again .

```
function Login() {
  const { data, isLoading, isFetching } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["/users"],
    queryFn: async () => {
      return fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
        .then((val) => {
          return val.json();
        })
        .then((v) => {
          return v;
        });
    },
    cacheTime : 300000,
  });
  console.log(isLoading, isFetching);
  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading ...</div>;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ margin: "20px 20px 20px 0px" }}>Login</div>
      <hr />
      {data?.map((eachdata) => {
        return <div key={eachdata.id}>{eachdata.username}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
export { Login };

//Home page

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ margin: "20px 20px 20px 0px" }}>Home</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add staleTime to your query options to specify how long the data is fresh and can be used without refetching.

```
const { data, isLoading, isFetching } = useQuery({
  queryKey: ["/users"],
  queryFn: async () => {
    // Fetch function
  },
  staleTime: 300000, // 5 minutes
  cacheTime: 300000, // 5 minutes
});
```

Comment: I test this but it refetch again